# Write byte array to ZipArchiveOutputStream

Tags: java, zip, apache-commons-compress

I need to create a zip file and am limited by the following conditions:

- The entries come as byte[] (or ByteArrayOutputStream) and not as File.
- The filenames for the entry can be non-ascii/UTF-8.
- JDK 1.6 or earlier

Since java.util.zip only supports UTF-8 filenames from JDK 1.7 and onward, it seems better to use commons-compress ZipArchiveOutputStream. But how to create a ZipEntryArchive based on a byte array or ByteArrayOutputStream rather than a File?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "non-UTF-8" - any Unicode character can be encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: @Jesper I meant "non-ascii", UTF-8, non-Latin...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following method takes a byte[] as input, produces a zip and returns its content as another byte[]. All is done in memory. No IO operations on the disk. I stripped exception handling for a better overview.

```
    byte[] zip(byte[] data, String filename) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipArchiveOutputStream zos = new ZipArchiveOutputStream(bos);

        ZipArchiveEntry entry = new ZipArchiveEntry(filename);
        entry.setSize(data.length);
        zos.putArchiveEntry(entry);
        zos.write(data);
        zos.closeArchiveEntry();

        zos.close();
        bos.close();

        return bos.toByteArray();       
   }
```

Does this solve your problem?